# How to clear cache data without delete my session data in Django 2.2.2

Tags: python, django

I am trying to delete the cache from django in browser without delete the session data of my website.

Comment: How about EditThisCookie Chrome browser extension? It lets you remove cookies partially.

Comment: I need to do it inside my django app

Comment: Please check this documentation part first https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#downstream-caches. You might want to use `cache_control` (with `max_age` maybe) decorator or `never_cache`. Or `patch_cache_control` (with private).